# shell scripting not executing

Tags: mysql, shell, iot

Why is this code not working properly?

```
mosquitto_sub -p 2025 -t test/topic >file1.txt
mysql  -u root -p"qwerty" test<<EOF
LOAD DATA LOCAL  INFILE '/home/arjun/file1.txt' INTO TABLE t1;
select value from t1;
EOF
```

I have tried to copy the data from the mosquitto subscriber to the text file and then copy the data to the mysql database.the data is copied into the text file but after that the script is not executed.

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: You should also include your error output.  It will assist anyone trying to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the `--local-infile` option when you call `mysql`.  I also added `-D yourDB` to specify that you want to use this database.  And I got rid of that `SELECT`...I don't know why you had it there.

```
mysql -u root -p"qwerty" -D yourDB --local-infile test << EOF
LOAD DATA LOCAL  INFILE '/home/arjun/file1.txt' INTO TABLE t1;
EOF
```

From the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html):

> **--local-infile** 
>   Enable or disable for LOCAL capability for LOAD DATA INFILE

Comment: Did you give the correct database name, and also what is your error output?

Comment: well their is no error message as such...the cursor in the command line just keeps blinking

Comment: How large is this file?